# Does anyone know how to Unzip password protected files in erlang

Tags: file, erlang, unzip

Have 3 questions

1. how to unzip or open a password protected zip file in erlang?
2. after unziping the zip file, sorting all files by extention some thing like filelib:wildcard("*.?erl")?
3. put all sorted files i different files i.e file:write(all *.erl -> to erlfile) and file:write(all *.beam -> to beamfile)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As for 1., I don't think you can do that easily. You have to call some external script and observe its behaviour through a port.

As for 2, you can do the following:

```
 Filenames = ["foo.erl", "bar.txt", "baz.erl"],
 Sorted = lists:keysort(1, [{filename:extension(Name), Name} || Name <- Filenames])
 [Name || {_, Name} <- Sorted].
```

As for 3, if space is no problem, then read all of them into memory, gather the data in an iolist() and write that one back to the desired output file. If space is a problem you need to stream data a bit and read in chunks.

Comment: what kind of script do you mean?

Comment: Normaly when i decompress a zip file I use: {ok,Filenames}=zip:extract(Pathtothefile). And Filenames is a list of other files like                                                      ["rabbitmq-server-2.7.0/src/worker_pool.erl",
     "rabbitmq-server-2.7.0/src/mirrored_supervisor_tests.erl",
     "rabbitmq-server-2.7.0/src/rabbit_binding.erl].             What I mean here is, How can I sort them to different files?